# Interpreting Netstat output

Tags: apache-2.2, netstat

I have a LAMP stack running Fedora 12 and I am run the following instruction through the command line on the server:
`netstat -anp |grep 'tcp\|udp' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

As far as I understand this should show me the IPs of the connected processes and how many connections per IP there are, correct?

I would need some help in interpreting the results. Out of 250 total connections, 140 don't show any IP (just a blank), 80 are from my slave DB, 20 are from IP 0.0.0.0 and only 10 are from what appears to be normal connections to the server.

My questions are thus:
1. What do the 140 blank IPs represent?
2. Why does my slave DB (MySQL) need 80 connections? Can this number be reduced? If so how?
3. What are 20 0.0.0.0 connections?

I apologise if this is a trivial question, but I am a relative newbie at this.

Adding part of the `netstat -anp` (just removed my servers IPs and had to trim because of post length limit):

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program nams
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2234                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1616/sshd  
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:443            201.23.177.150:18846        SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:443            182.156.150.187:41594       SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:443            151.61.126.161:50591        SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:443            119.30.38.84:51449          SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:443            190.121.239.151:38961       SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:443            201.23.160.144:54884        SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:443            151.61.126.161:50592        SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1625/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1625/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2393/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1625/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1625/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1302/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:80             201.23.177.72:17927         SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1436/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44183               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1356/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1718/master
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46961          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46978          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47147          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47264          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47250          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47243          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47273          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47267          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46955          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     70 my-server-ip:47282          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25697/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47034          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:41433          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 24983/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46986          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47247          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     52 my-server-ip:2234           177.42.224.14:57947         ESTABLISHED 25774/0
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46969          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     70 my-server-ip:41504          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 24982/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47271          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46970          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     69 my-server-ip:47275          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25836/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46953          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47080          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47094          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47019          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46956          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46963          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     70 my-server-ip:46930          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 24976/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46906          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47272          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     70 my-server-ip:46888          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25709/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:2234           177.42.224.14:64099         ESTABLISHED 25866/sshd: root@no
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47112          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47221          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0    240 my-server-ip:47276          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25374/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47109          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0    240 my-server-ip:47278          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25711/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:41195          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 24966/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46975          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47027          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     86 my-server-ip:47281          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25599/httpd
tcp        0     70 my-server-ip:46993          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25841/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47119          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47165          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47032          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47054          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      1 my-server-ip:47322          94.100.187.197:25           SYN_SENT    25909/smtp
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47185          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0     70 my-server-ip:46893          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25712/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:41273          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 24974/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47076          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47214          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47241          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47176          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47012          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:3306           my-slave-db-ip:57117        ESTABLISHED 2393/mysqld
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:143            177.42.224.14:62179         ESTABLISHED 23981/imap-login
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47060          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0    240 my-server-ip:47280          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25602/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46967          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47003          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46972          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:46946          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47202          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47017          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0    644 my-server-ip:46811          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25604/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47030          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47253          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47044          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47274          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47096          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0    240 my-server-ip:47277          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25842/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47269          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0    240 my-server-ip:47279          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25506/httpd
tcp        0    490 my-server-ip:46673          my-slave-db-ip:3306         ESTABLISHED 25665/httpd
tcp        0      0 my-server-ip:47045          my-slave-db-ip:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 :::2234                     :::*                        LISTEN      1616/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      24956/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      1302/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      24956/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      1436/cupsd
tcp        0      0 :::25                       :::*                        LISTEN      1718/master
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:88.154.220.155:33982 ESTABLISHED 25842/httpd
tcp        0     47 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:186.122.246.21:52748 ESTABLISHED 25837/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:83.178.136.202:55078 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55984  ESTABLISHED 25608/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:83.178.136.202:41350 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:90.210.173.3:51483   ESTABLISHED 25697/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55965  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.144.158.19:40385 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:83.178.136.202:47388 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0   6230 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:106.197.152.19:48216 FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:80.7.104.8:36967     CLOSE_WAIT  24974/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55968  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:93.146.164.167:50292 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:206.53.54.187:38688  ESTABLISHED 25374/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:81.136.129.137:52966 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55966  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:220.255.1.131:8102   TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:41.222.192.226:64538 ESTABLISHED 25832/httpd
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:80.7.104.8:60849     CLOSE_WAIT  24966/httpd
tcp        0    513 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:187.80.54.17:41707   FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:80.7.104.8:57877     CLOSE_WAIT  24983/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:180.178.25.61:5453   ESTABLISHED 25506/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.144.158.195:4773 FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:79.26.90.157:24409   TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:197.200.85.248:13747 ESTABLISHED 25599/httpd
tcp        0   6230 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:41.53.45.194:33870   FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55960  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:2.158.95.179:60733   ESTABLISHED 24976/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:213.30.118.99:55288  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.144.158.195:4769 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:187.80.191.105:45382 FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55967  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:83.35.243.61:53344   TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:83.178.136.202:40979 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:200.81.44.250:31556  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:80.7.104.8:57631     CLOSE_WAIT  24982/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55980  ESTABLISHED 25605/httpd
tcp        0  11201 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:93.65.181.47:53717   FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:188.80.5.246:53477   FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:41.190.8.31:12272    ESTABLISHED 25217/httpd
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:80.7.104.8:39440     CLOSE_WAIT  25712/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:178.96.198.45:43412  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0   6230 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:41.17.156.241:36223  FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55983  ESTABLISHED 25713/httpd
tcp        0    213 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:187.119.160.67:59660 FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55964  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        1    455 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:187.141.84.94:56325  CLOSING     -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:197.252.77.141:5340  FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:201.52.83.193:50966  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:151.26.113.212:26581 FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:83.178.136.202:56702 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0   6230 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:95.66.57.147:60665   FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:46.222.107.130:55683 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:201.23.160.151:29801 CLOSE_WAIT  25709/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:85.77.28.94:47593    ESTABLISHED 25841/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:151.60.30.6:48331    FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:117.229.95.166:48579 ESTABLISHED 25711/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:83.178.61.76:37227   TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:83.178.136.202:43040 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:80.7.104.8:56232     CLOSE_WAIT  25604/httpd
tcp        0   6230 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:41.190.3.232:17447   FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55985  ESTABLISHED 24991/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:186.182.113.12:59188 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        1      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:201.23.160.151:28767 CLOSE_WAIT  25665/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:178.240.115.10:53294 FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:85.62.234.254:45417  TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:2.232.62.163:43565   FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:117.230.223.85:48221 ESTABLISHED 25602/httpd
tcp        0      1 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.60.238.52:42449  FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0     28 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:101.2.90.246:50399   CLOSING     -
tcp        0    513 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:49.201.248.245:60295 FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.4.135.249:65105  ESTABLISHED 25836/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:201.191.198.96:32171 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55982  ESTABLISHED 25843/httpd
tcp        0      1 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:189.131.12.46:55981  FIN_WAIT1   25546/httpd
tcp        0   3533 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:189.116.225.43:52473 ESTABLISHED 25727/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:80      ::ffff:83.178.136.202:40922 TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:my-server-ip:443     ::ffff:41.206.15.18:9701    TIME_WAIT   -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39616               0.0.0.0:*                               1356/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               1384/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353                0.0.0.0:*                               1336/avahi-daemon:
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               1302/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60021               0.0.0.0:*                               1336/avahi-daemon:
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:629                 0.0.0.0:*                               1302/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                               1436/cupsd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:684                 0.0.0.0:*                               1356/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                                    1302/rpcbind
udp        0      0 :::629                      :::*                                    1302/rpcbind
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10999  1436/cupsd          /var/run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11536  1625/dovecot        /var/run/dovecot/dict-server
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11538  1625/dovecot        /var/run/dovecot/login/default
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11543  1625/dovecot        /var/run/dovecot/auth-worker.1626
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11892  1718/master         public/cleanup
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11924  1718/master         public/flush
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11944  1718/master         public/showq
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11567  1626/dovecot-auth   /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10206  1316/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7400   1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     19051  2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  23     [ ]         DGRAM                    10066  1256/rsyslogd       /dev/log
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7555   551/udevd           @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11146  1469/hald           @/org/freedesktop/hal/udev_event
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11899  1718/master         private/tlsmgr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11903  1718/master         private/rewrite
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11908  1718/master         private/bounce
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11912  1718/master         private/defer
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11916  1718/master         private/trace
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11920  1718/master         private/verify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11928  1718/master         private/proxymap
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11932  1718/master         private/proxywrite
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11936  1718/master         private/smtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11940  1718/master         private/relay
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11948  1718/master         private/error
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11952  1718/master         private/retry
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11956  1718/master         private/discard
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11960  1718/master         private/local
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11964  1718/master         private/virtual
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11968  1718/master         private/lmtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11972  1718/master         private/anvil
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11976  1718/master         private/scache
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11082  1469/hald           @/var/run/hald/dbus-zZ2k930EI0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11561  1626/dovecot-auth   /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11124  1469/hald           @/var/run/hald/dbus-3PhM3NhFOT
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10147  1302/rpcbind        /var/run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10285  1336/avahi-daemon:  /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11594  1635/saslauthd      /var/run/saslauthd/mux
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12223  1762/abrtd          /var/run/abrt/abrt.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11055  1461/acpid          /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11440  1595/pcscd          /var/run/pcscd.comm
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    561886 25911/bounce
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561870 1978/tlsmgr         private/tlsmgr
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561869 25910/smtp
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    561861 25910/smtp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561856 1978/tlsmgr         private/tlsmgr
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561855 25909/smtp
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    561847 25909/smtp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561857 25909/smtp          private/smtp
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561845 2111/qmgr
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561844 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561843 25906/proxymap
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561842 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561841 25906/proxymap
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    561829 25906/proxymap
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561837 25906/proxymap      private/proxymap
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561828 25905/trivial-rewri
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    561820 25905/trivial-rewri
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561838 25905/trivial-rewri private/rewrite
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561819 2111/qmgr
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561804 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561803 25697/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561802 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561801 25697/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561798 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561797 25599/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561796 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561795 25599/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561792 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561791 25602/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561790 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561789 25602/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561787 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561786 25506/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561785 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561784 25506/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561782 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561781 25711/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561780 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561779 25711/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561777 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561776 25842/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561775 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561774 25842/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561772 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561771 25374/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561770 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561769 25374/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561760 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561759 25836/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561758 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     561757 25836/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560678 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560677 25841/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560676 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560675 25841/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560401 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560400 24976/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560399 2393/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560398 24976/httpd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     560346 1626/dovecot-auth   /var/run/dovecot/login/default
```

Answer (score 3):

> - What do the 140 blank IPs represent?
> - What are 20 0.0.0.0 connections?

You passed the `-a` option which includes processes that are listening, and Unix Domain Sockets.  Try running `netstat -anp` without any of the filtering/formatting stuff and you will see the full output.  The `0.0.0.0` almost certainly represent listening processes.  The blanks are almost certainly domain sockets.

> Why does my slave DB (MySQL) need 80 connections?  Can this number be reduced?

Because there are 80 things connecting too it?   Look at the full netstat output, and you will be able to learn a lot more.  Without any more details nobody here can make any useful guesses.  The number may be able to be reduced, again we would need more details.

Comment: Thanks Zoredache, I've added an almost full ouput as SF does not allow me to post more than 30.000 chars.

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0:993 (at local address column) is usually shown in the LISTENING state, indicating your device's dovecot (IMAP/POP3 mail server) is waiting from incoming connection on the port 993 of all IPv4 addresses. Since it is now not connected (to remote application, see below) so the IPv4 is still unknown or empty.
Correspondingly, 0.0.0.0:* indicating the remote(foreign) application is also not connected to your device so remote end's IPv4 address is unknown or empty, port is also unknown.

In short, 0.0.0.0 means nothing is connected in IPv4

Once connected (ESTABLISHED state) it becomes an active connection, you should see some IP addresses on both local and foreign column. Make sense? Depending on the kind of connection, the local IP address can be local LAN address like 192.168.0.33, loopback address like 127.0.01, or Internet IP 129.128.30.130 address, while the foreign address will have corresponding type of IP addresses.

For IPv6 LISTENING state, same explanation applies, the local address will become :::443 (if you are running https), foreign address is :::*. First two :: is empty address, the 3rd : is colon mark.

These applies to both TCP and UDP connections. I assume you know the difference between TCP and UDP connections.